# How to remove the last 3 div inside a div

Tags: javascript

removing the last 3 divs inside the div using native javascript

It should first look like this:

```
<div id="name">
      <div>one</div>
      <div>two</div>
      <div>three</div>
      <div>four</div>
      <div>five</div>
</div>
```

After removing it:

```
<div id="name">
      <div>one</div>
      <div>two</div>
</div>
```

I tried removing it by assigning individual id names on them but its impossible to track the changes since its constantly changing and shuffling.

Comment: And what code have you tried ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last three can be identified with `.slice(-3)` on the node list (when converted to array):

```js
const parent = document.querySelector("#name");
[...parent.children].slice(-3).forEach(parent.removeChild.bind(parent));
```

```html
<div id="name">
      <div>one</div>
      <div>two</div>
      <div>three</div>
      <div>four</div>
      <div>five</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can select the last 3 divs with `:nth-last-child(-n+3)` and delete them in an iteration

```js
document.querySelectorAll('#name > div:nth-last-child(-n+3)').forEach(n => {
  n.parentNode.removeChild(n)
})
```

```html
<div id="name">
  <div>one</div>
  <div>two</div>
  <div>three</div>
  <div>four</div>
  <div>five</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get all children nodes of `#name` with `document.querySelectorAll('#name>div')`. The rest should be easy enough:

```js
function deleteLast3() {
  var childrens = document.querySelectorAll('#name>div');
  for (var index = 0; index < childrens.length; index++) {
    if (index >= childrens.length - 3) childrens[index].remove();
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="name">
  <div>one</div>
  <div>two</div>
  <div>three</div>
  <div>four</div>
  <div>five</div>
</div>
<button onclick="deleteLast3()">Delete 3</button>
```

Comment: `.forEach()` does not work on node lists in all browsers.

Comment: @ScottMarcus what browser are you talking about? https://caniuse.com/#search=foreach . Anyway, a for loop is fine as well.

Comment: Any version of IE.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, the OP is not asking about IE. I honestly don't feel we should write answers for such an outdated browser, except when it is part of the question.

Comment: @trincot Regardless of how you feel about it, IE is still used in the workplace by millions of users. Also, as you well know, most people don't post questions that ask how to do something like this in one specific browser so giving an answer that works for all browsers is always the better choice IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the set in reverse and remove the first 3 you find:

```js
let divs = document.querySelectorAll("#name > div"); // Get all the child divs

// Set up loop to go from highest index to lowest, but not to the first two
for(var i = divs.length -1; i > 1; i--){
  // Remove node at the current index
  divs[i].parentNode.removeChild(divs[i]);
}
```

```html
<div id="name">
      <div>one</div>
      <div>two</div>
      <div>three</div>
      <div>four</div>
      <div>five</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to answer the question "how to keep the first two", not "how to remove the last three".

Comment: @trincot It sure does because the loop counts in reverse. All that one would have to do is alter the loop condition for a set of a different length. Or, add a counter if you like. The point is to show how to remove items so I showed a loop that does that.

Comment: Your `for` loop's exit condition is expressed using the number of items to *keep*, not in the number of items to *remove*. Add a few more `div` to your HTML and running this code will delete all of them, except the first two.

Comment: @trincot I don't think you read my last comment. A simple change of the loop condition solves that or you can add a second counter if you like. The point of how to loop and remove items was made.

Comment: I did read your last comment. I think you got the point I made in my original comment.

Comment: @trincot But I don't think you got mine since you repeated your inaccurate comment that I had already responded to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

**EDIT:** using `parentDivDOM.children` you retrieve all the direct chilldren of your parent div. Then, starting from the last one, you check if it's a `div` checking its tag name: if it is, you delete it.

Notice  that you also keep track of how many `div` you have deleted with the `count` variable.

```js
const parentDivDOM = document.getElementById("name");
const childrenDOM = parentDivDOM.children;

for (let i=childrenDOM.length-1, count=0; i>=0 && count<3; i--) {
  if (childrenDOM[i].tagName === "DIV") {
    childrenDOM[i].parentElement.removeChild(childrenDOM[i]);
    count++;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="name">
      <div>one</div>
      <div>two</div>
      <div>three</div>
      <div>four</div>
      <div>five</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good answers on Stack Overflow don't just solve the problem. They explain how they solve it.

Comment: Well, I guest it was pretty self-explanatory enough. I've added an explanation though :)

Answer (score 1):

Although the question for javascript I would suggest to do this with jQuery.

```js
$('#name').find("div").slice(-3).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="name">
      <div>one</div>
      <div>two</div>
      <div>three</div>
      <div>four</div>
      <div>five</div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: didn't get you. Can you please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a try

```js
function deleteLast3() {
document.querySelectorAll('#name div')
.forEach(function (x, i, self){
if (self.length -3 <= i) 
    x.remove();
});
}
```

```html
<div id="name">
  <div>one</div>
  <div>two</div>
  <div>three</div>
  <div>four</div>
  <div>five</div>
</div>
<button onclick="deleteLast3()">Delete 3</button>
```